# Unexpected end of JSON input only on one table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I've made some code with jQuery that whenever I press a button I shall retrieve some information. This works fine with 3 of my tables, but of some reason that last table wont work.

My jQuery code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
 url: "ajax.php",
 type: "get",
 datatype: "json",
 success: function(data){
  var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  $.each(parsed, function(i){
   var oldhtml = $('p').html();
   $("p").html(oldhtml + "<br>Name: " + parsed[i]['name']);
  });
 }
)};
```

So I have this connected to a button and an onclick function. So my PHP code echoes an associative array, and it works fine with my tables moment1, moment2, moment4. But whenever I try to use it on my table called konsult, I get syntax error.

> "Unexpected end of JSON input at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (anonymous)".

It it something with my table or what is the problem? I use the same code to get info from the first tables. I only switch the tablename and instead of "parsed[i]['name']" I have "parsed[i]['titel']"

EDIT: It seems to be fixed. One of my cells had a "ö" which for some reason gave me syntax error.

Comment: The returned JSON is invalid so check the response of the server

Comment: I did as you said, and the response was fine. What I noticed is that one of my cell contained info with a "ö" which didn't work that good. So I changed it, and now it works fine.